# Client failover for qpid/amqp jms client?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, amqp, qpid

Following the wiki page https://cwiki.apache.org/qpid/amqp-java-jms-messaging-client.html to https://cwiki.apache.org/qpid/connection-url-format.html.

Simple me expected qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-0.20-sources.jar to accept the URI format, but it seems to disregard just about everything - especially the "brokerlist" option?

For example:

```
amqp://guest:guest@nowhere?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672;tcp://localhost:15672'&failover='roundrobin'
```

However the ConnectionFactory insist on using the `<clientid>` as broker host, and adds default port to it.

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious here...

Broker is ActiveMQ 5.8.0, BTW.

Comment: Try putting the broker list in brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection string you are using is pre-AMQP 1.0, new connection string should be of the following format without brokerlist

amqp://guest:guest@nowhere?remote-host=default

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the virtual host in your url: amqp://guest:guest@clientid/host?